# VB.Net Cant create "new line" "string"

Tags: vb.net, string, join, newline

I am in need of assistance... i am trying to create a textfile with links in it. the code i have..

```
dim domain as string = "http://www.mywebsite/"
dim name as string = "username"
Dim link As String = New String("domain" & "name")
                TextBox1.AppendText(link & Environment.NewLine)
Msgbox(textBox1.lines(0))
```

The problem is that MsgBox  only shows up as "http://www.mywebsite/". the textbox does show "http://www.mywebsite/username" but when copied to text document it is:
 Line0: http://www.mywebsite/
 Line1:username
 any ideas... tried using 
`Dim link As String = String.Join(domain & name)` but that doesnt work nor does 
`Dim link As String = new String.Join(domain & name)`
i need 
Msgbox(textBox1.lines(0))  to display "http://www.mywebsite/username" not one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

That was quick got a message saying to use. `Dim link As String = String.Concat(domain & name)`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should move to StringBuilder first import **Imports System.Text**

```
'create a string with multiple lines
Dim a As New StringBuilder
a.AppendLine("hi")
a.AppendLine("there")
a.AppendLine("this")
a.AppendLine("is")
a.AppendLine("a")
a.AppendLine("test")

'read will makes read line by line
Dim read As String() = a.ToString.Split(vbNewLine)
'count has number of lines
Dim count As Integer = a.ToString().Split(vbNewLine).Length - 1

'lines will be added to combobox one by one
For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(read(i))
Next
```

you just should edit it to suits your needs i didnt understand  what you needed exactly